# Libgdx - Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, exception, libgdx, game-physics

https://gist.github.com/Redas17/539382e654fe13613f70cf21cf515f22 - That is a link to all the classes I have coded.

Hello I need your help, I am working on a Mario game from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8g44JssVmc&t=3s

On video 21 a feature was added to spawn mushrooms whenever a coin brick was hit. As soon as I added this feature, the game starts, but in 1 of 4 times (about) it's crashes when I hit coin brick with mushroom. I was getting this error

https://gist.github.com/Redas17/90d81231c16668e1ee6299ff13ad229b

Then I found a blogpost, who "found" solution. Here it is  -

Today, I finally had the time to dig into my code (since I don't use Brent's code 1:1, I like to "tidy it up" after each lesson so it adheres to my own standards) and managed to find the culprit. The problem was in the end that `PlayScreen.update()` tried to set the bodies of destroyed Goombas active - that caused the Box2d engine to try to access memory that is not available anymore (Box2D is written in C, there is just a tiny Java-Wrapper around it so it can do that).The solution is something like this:
In PlayScreen.update() instead of

```
if(enemy.getX() < player.getX() + 224 / MarioBros.PPM) {
                enemy.b2body.setActive(true);
            }
```

**do something like**

```
if(!enemy.isDestroyed() && enemy.getX() < player.getX() + 224 / MarioBros.PPM) {
                enemy.b2body.setActive(true);
            }
```

For that to work we need to create this variable and method in Enemy:

```
protected boolean destroyed;

public boolean isDestroyed() {
                return destroyed
            }
```

and remove the variable "destroyed" from Goomba and Turtle.

And guess what? Problem still there, but error changed to -

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.redsoft.game.Sprites.Items.ItemDef cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:652)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:647)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:344)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:321)
    at com.redsoft.game.Screens.PlayScreen.spawnItem(PlayScreen.java:80)
    at com.redsoft.game.Sprites.TileObjects.Coin.onHeadHit(Coin.java:36)
    at com.redsoft.game.Tools.WorldContactListener.beginContact(WorldContactListener.java:30)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.beginContact(World.java:985)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniStep(Native Method)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.step(World.java:689)
    at com.redsoft.game.Screens.PlayScreen.update(PlayScreen.java:116)
    at com.redsoft.game.Screens.PlayScreen.render(PlayScreen.java:143)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.redsoft.game.MarioBros.render(MarioBros.java:48)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

Interesting that when I comment lines from the blogpost

```
if (!enemy.isDestroyed() && enemy.getX() < player.getX() + 224 / MarioBros.PPM) {
                enemy.b2body.setActive(true);
            }
```

I am getting last error, not fatal error [gdx-box2d64.dll+0xbd0d] but  `Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.redsoft.game.Sprites.Items.ItemDef cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable` - but in the same circumstances, so maybe it's kind of the same thing, well. Sorry for long post, but I am new into LibGDX. I have researched for two days without any solution.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `itemsToSpawn` collection in `PlayScreen` is `PriorityQueue<ItemDef>`.

here you are trying to add ItemDef object to itemsSpawn:

```
public void spawnItem(ItemDef idef) {
     itemsToSpawn.add(idef);
}
```

But `PriorityQueue` allows only `Comparable` elements.

So solution is change it to `LinkedBlockingQueue` like in tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, you are my hero!